# Jquery navigation bar style depending on current page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pure HTML/CSS navigation bar in 4 pages, like this:

```
<nav id="bar">
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="aa.html">AA</a></li>
<li><a href="bb.html">BB</a></li>
<li id="page">CC</li>
<li><a href="dd.html">DD</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I can get the page name using javascript, with

```
var pagename = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
```

I want to use Jquery to add the same code to every page, and, depending on the html page, remove the a link and change the id using something like (pseudocode):

```
$("#nav").append(<li><a href="aa.html">AA</a></li>
<li><a href="bb.html">BB</a></li><li><a href="cc.html">CC</a></li><li><a href="dd.html">DD</a></li>

$("#nav").find(pagename).parent().removelink_and_add_the_"page"_id()
```

That is, if the current page is DD.html, the navigation bar changes the `<li><a href="dd.html">DD</a></li>` to `<li id="page">DD</li>`

Is it posible? Any hint?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: This seems a bit like an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). What is the actual goal? Maybe this isn't the right strategy.

Comment: It's also not clear what you're asking. What part of that process are you having trouble with? Please see [ask] and take the [tour] and revise to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//supose pagename is DD.html
//var pagename = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
var pagename = "dd.html";

$("#nav").append('<li><a href="aa.html">AA</a></li><li><a href="bb.html">BB</a></li><li><a href="cc.html">CC</a></li><li><a href="dd.html">DD</a></li>')

var $aElem = $("#nav").find("a[href='" + pagename + "']");
//set id and text/html of li parent (if is just text use text() instead html())
$aElem.parent().attr("id", "page").html($aElem.html());
//bye a element
$aElem.remove();
//checking changes in li element
console.log($("#page")[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">

</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!, it is the solution I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

Find the `<a>` using css attribute selectors:

```
let myElem = $("a[href='dd.html']")
```

Then change the id of the parent, add the DD text to the parent, and finally use `.remove()` on myElem